# Share windows directory to Linux docker container

Tags: docker

I've been trying the whole day to accomplish a simplistic example of sharing a Windows directory to Linux container running on Windows Docker host.
Have read all the guidelines and run the following:

```
docker run -it --rm -p 5002:80 --name mount-test --mount type=bind,source=D:\DockerArea\PortScanner,target=/app/PortScannerWorkingDirectory barebonewebapi:latest
```

The origin `PortScanner` directory on host machine has got some text file in it. The container is created successfully.
The issue is that when I'm trying to

```
docker exec -it mount-test /bin/bash
```

and then list the mounted directory in the container `PortScannerWorkingDirectory` - it just shows that it's empty. Nor the C# code can read the contents of the host file in the mapped directory.
Am I missing something simple here? I feel like I got stuck and can't share files on the host Windows machine to Linux container.

Comment: you already tried: `docker run -it --rm -p 5002:80 --name mount-test -v /app/PortScannerWorkingDirectory:D:\DockerArea\PortScanner barebonewebapi:latest`?

Comment: this was a sort of an obvious attempt - tried it without any luck. though, in your example parameter sequence should've been inverted `D:\DockerArea\PortScanner:/app/PortScannerWorkingDirectory`. Also, as far as I understood, `-v` is a soft of legacy and now `--mount` is more recommended since it's more explicit. I'm about to raise an issue on Microsoft Github since no any attempt brought any positive result. Docker version 18.09.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several days of dealing with the issue I've found quite apparent answer. Although I had had C and D drives already shared to Docker in Docker settings I did an experiment and **re-shared both drives** (there's a special button Reset Credentials for that purpose in Docker agent settings for Windows). After that the issue is resolved. So saving it here with the hope that it may help someone else since this seems to be a glitch with permissions or similar.
The issue is quite hard to diagnose - when there's an issue the Docker container just silently writes into its writable layer and no error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `docker settings -> shared drives -> reset credentials`.
and then click the drive and click apply button.

then execute following command as suggested by docker

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data
```